# Angularjs Elemento duplicando

Tags: html, angularjs, morris

Fiz um gráfico com Morris.js https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/donuts.html

e coloquei ele dentro de um retorno de uma consulta, até ai tudo certo, porem quando chamo essa consulta novamente para gerar outros dados no gráfico, ele gera outro gráfico, está duplicando, ao invés de apenas trocar as informações, ele cria outro gráfico e fica 2

[image: Erro angularjs]

Conforme vou trocando o option, ele vai gerando um novo gráfico...

Meu código

```
 $scope.selectAction = function(myOption) {
       $http.get('http://localhost/Angularjs/php/TotalAlunos.php?cod=' + $scope.myOption.id).then(function(result){    
        Morris.Donut({
          element: 'donut-example',
          data: [
            {label: "In-Store Sales", value: result.data.total},
            {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
          ]
        });
      });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não conheço esse morrisjs, mas dando uma pesquisada eu encontrei algo que talvez possa ajudar.

Tente criar um gráfico só e apenas atualizar seus dados em cada chamada.
Algo tipo isso:

```
var donut = Morris.Donut({
      element: 'donut-example',
      data: [
          {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 0},
          {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 0}
      ]
    });

 $scope.selectAction = function(myOption) {
   $http.get('http://localhost/Angularjs/php/TotalAlunos.php?cod=' + $scope.myOption.id).then(function(result){    
    donut.setData([
        {label: "In-Store Sales", value: result.data.total},
        {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
      ]);
  });
};
```